# Download a video from news website

Tags: command-line, video, permissions, wget, terminal.app

I was on the local news today and would like to download the video from their web page. I have been strugling with terminal for an hour now. What is the best way to download a video like this?

https://www.kens5.com/video/money/business/made-in-sa/made-in-sa-ragnar-handcrafted-furniture-and-sawmill/273-622570f2-900a-44d5-af57-bea8a40bacea?jwsource=cl

I ran an older version of wget which was having SSL problems. I updated my homebrew instal and reinstaled wget. I have the new wget instaled but not linked. I have tried `brew link wget` but get an error because of this folder not being writable. I have tried to `sudo rm /usr/local/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES` and reinstal. I have also tried `sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/local/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES`

This is the error I get: Linking /usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.20.3_1... Error: Could not symlink share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo /usr/local/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES is not writable.

Comment: Easiest might be to contact the station manager at KENS in TX and ask for a copy! You might also get some interesting outtakes. https://www.kens5.com/contact-us

Comment: I tried contacting them first. They said they can't give a copy and I would need to contact an outside company to get a copy.

Comment: There is a local company which will sell me the video for $80 which is what I'm trying to save with this method.

Answer (score -2):

Just found answer, use firefox and a download helper.

Comment: Thank you for following up. It would help other users if you say *why* Firefox in particular and which 'download helper' you used, and how you used it.